# Blueimp PHP and jQuery file upload chunking fails after first chunk

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I'm having trouble implementing the chunking function in Blueimp.
I need the chunking function to upload large files to my server but I am unable to raise the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`.
The documentation states it supported by default and only requires below code to activate it.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    maxChunkSize: 10000000 // 10 MB
});
```

Which to be fair is not wrong, however the upload fails after the first chunk has been uploaded.

Is there something else not in the documentation that is required to use it successfully?

The code I am using is pretty much identical to the demo Basic Plus but I have included it below anyway

**jQuery**

```
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
'use strict';
// Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
var url = window.location.hostname === 'example.com' ? '//classes/' : 'classes/',
    uploadButton = $('<button/>')
        .addClass('btn btn-primary')
        .prop('disabled', true)
        .text('Processing...')
        .on('click', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data();
            $this
                .off('click')
                .text('Abort')
                .on('click', function () {
                    $this.remove();
                    data.abort();
                });
            data.submit().always(function () {
                $this.remove();
            });
        });
$('#fileupload').fileupload({

    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    //multipart: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4|mpeg4)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 2000000000, // 2 GB
    maxChunkSize: 2000000, // 2 MB
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 620,
    previewMaxHeight: 349,
    previewCrop: true

}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
                .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
        if (!index) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
        }
        node.appendTo(data.context);
    });

}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
    }

}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress').show();
    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );

}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        if (file.url) {
            var link = $('<a>')
                .attr('target', '_blank')
                .prop('href', file.url);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .wrap(link);
        } else if (file.error) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        }
    });

}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index) {
        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .append('<br>')
            .append(error);

    });

}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

**HTML Form**

```
<!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <input id="fileupload" class="adminFields" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
```

Comment: You have to set multipart to false. You have that commented out.

Comment: I have tried setting `multipart: false` both on and off. I left it off after last attempt

Comment: Have you seen any errors in the logs?

Comment: Not that I've been able to see. Anything I should look for specifically? jQuery is not my forte.

Comment: Ignore that. Just found an error. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.135.7.15:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=3003356007. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. `

Comment: It appears as if you're trying to make an illegal cross-domain AJAX request.

Comment: Everything is contained within the same server so I would have thought this should not be an issue. How would I resolve such an error

Comment: You're going to have to track down where the request is being made and change the config to accept CORS. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: There is also another 404 error in there. Could this potentially be the source or be contributing to the header error?